# Update Lambda function upon commit

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am looking to develop a work flow as follows

1. The developers commit their code to github
2. As soon as the Master branch changes (merge), through web hooks, it triggers a AWS CodePipeline where Build happens as a second stage using CodeBuild
3. Ideally the work flow exists already for CodeDeploy or ECS where the built artifact replaces the task definition in ECS and updates the service. But I am looking for a lambda deployment.

It means, the built artifact or the zip file that gets uploaded to S3 bucket by CodeBuild should trigger a lambda function and also the lambda function code should be updated from the artifacts of CodeBuild.

Now I know one of the triggers for Lambda is S3 but it only triggers a already defined lambda function to execute but not update the function and execute it.

From the console, I do not think there is a way to do this directly.  As complicated as it sounds, I am hoping there is a way.

Any pointers in that direction would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using `AWS CloudFormation` to do my `AWS Lambda` deployment. In this case my `AWS CodePipeline` got 3 Stages (for simplicity):

1. Stage "Source": GitHub
2. Stage "Build": `AWS CodeBuild`
3. Stage "Deploy": `AWS CloudFormation`

Inside the Build Stage i am doing the typical building procedure `npm install`, `npm test`, etc.

**Important here**: in the end of my build i am using [`aws cloudformation package`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/package.html) which puts my code together, uploads it automatically to S3 and generates a final `AWS CloudFormation` template which i am then use in the 3. Stage "Deploy".

Comment: Based on your idea I built up a SAM template but the exact same steps. Thank you

Comment: @SriharshaPolimetla, can you please share the SAM template that you built

Comment: @Balakrishna https://github.com/S-Polimetla/lambda-dynamodb-api-sam  Maybe this repo helps you